# The density of minimal polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be a number field, i.e., a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. By the primitive element theorem there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Let

$$\displaystyle S_K = \{\alpha \in K : K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\}.$$

For a polynomial $f = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, define the height of $f$ to be $h(f) = \max_{0 \leq i \leq n} |a_i|$.

For each $\alpha \in S_K$, define $f_\alpha$ to be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Namely $f_\alpha$ is the unique polynomial with integer coefficients whose height is minimal among all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for which $\alpha$ is a root, and such that the leading coefficient of $f_\alpha$ is positive.

Now define $f_K$ to be a polynomial with positive leading coefficient which has the smallest height among $\{f_\alpha : \alpha \in S_K\}$. $f_K$ necessarily exists by the well-ordering property of the natural numbers. We then say that $f_K$ is a minimal polynomial of $K$. Let $\mathcal{S}_n$ denote the set of minimal polynomials of degree $n$ fields. Put

$$\displaystyle N_n(X) = \sum_{\substack{f \in \mathcal{S}_n \\ h(f) \leq X}} 1.$$

Does the limit

$$\displaystyle \lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N_n(X)}{X^{n+1}}$$

exist? If so, what is it expected to be? If not, does one have estimates for

$$\displaystyle \liminf_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N_n(X)}{X^{n+1}} \text{ and } \limsup_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N_n(X)}{X^{n+1}}?$$

Comment: Why is $f_K$ unique?

Comment: I was careful not to assert that $f_K$ is unique; it may very well not be. However, there will still be finitely many of them because there can only be a finite number of polynomials of given height.

Comment: I see. I think it's more a language issue; when you call $f_K$ '*the* polynomial with positive leading coefficient which has the smallest height' it implies uniqueness.

Comment: I see; the language is indeed flawed. I will edit the question

Comment: The phrase, "minimal polynomial for $\alpha$," is already taken, and with a different meaning. It's not even clear to me that your "minimal polynomial" is even irreducible (over the rationals).